# Asp MVC: How get roles from ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In ASP.NET MVC 5, in a controller, I have take the user that has make the request with:

```
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

With the ApplicationUser instance, how can i get all the Roles of the user?

Answer (score 12):

You can get user and assigned roles by using UserManager.

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

and then you can get your user like you already did, and also you can get roles for particular user by calling GetRoles method

```
userManager.GetRoles(userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> roles = new UserManager().GetRoles(userIdString)).ToList();
```

below needed classes were created automatically in ASP.NET 4.5 project using VS 2015 using . the file name is **IdentityModels.cs**.

default 4 Nuget packages are installed including **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi v5.2.3**

```
 public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public UserManager()
            : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
        {
        }
    }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!