# Get the list of Roles in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, role-manager

I have following methods to get the list of roles stored in `AspNetRoles`

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
    {
        //Get the list of Roles
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");

        return View();
    }
```

then I get it in view as follows

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">
            Select User Role
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
                @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

but once I load the page I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error

> Line 175:            ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await
>   RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");

This is `RoleManager` Definition

```
    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
```

this is `ApplicationRoleManager` Model

```
// Configure the RoleManager used in the application. RoleManager is defined in the ASP.NET Identity core assembly
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975075/asp-mvc-how-get-roles-from-applicationuser/34975588#34975588

Comment: @IMU actually I want get available roles , not assigned user's role or current users

Comment: @dotctor appreciate your suggestion , but I read that question very well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Startup.Auth, reference the RoleManager like this:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Add this reference
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
    }
```

Make sure your Controller includes this constructor:

```
        // Include this
        private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
        // You already have this
        public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager { get { return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>(); } private set { _roleManager = value; } }
```

Rebuild, try again and hopefully this will sort it out.

Comment: thanks for your guidance , once I did that my all other tables gone :(

Comment: @kez - I don't understand what you mean by "all other tables gone" ..?

Comment: it deleted all my tables, remain only ASpNet identity tables, another thing is, once I add new table to this database that consist default aspnet identity tables , then I debug the program its deleting all the newly added tables , and deleted all the data inside in asnet identity tables, how to avoid this

Comment: @kez - adding the lines as indicated will not take out database tables, they just reference the RoleManager. Please check that you didn't just copy and paste ConfigureAuth because (one thing that might cause it) is that it should also include:            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create); and probably other things. It may also be another problem with your re-build generating your tables if you are using code-first. Please check that you *add* the lines indicated, but leave your other code the same.

Comment: This solved it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `RoleManager.Roles` property. Seems that it does not return anything from DB. Also be sure that you have at least one role entity in `UserRoles` table

Comment: where I can find that property , in IdentityModel.cs ?

Comment: @kez Just do a var test = RoleManager.Roles; and debug to see what you get.

Comment: Yep its null ,how to load values then

Comment: @kez, If you really want to get all your roles from database you can use `GetRolesAsync()` method from manager. It return you the same result as  using of `Roles` property.

Comment: I get the same problem and when i looked into `Identity` code I found that framework tries to return instance of `IQueryable<T>` and this is cause internal error in it